# How to write URL in string array in android

Tags: android, string, url

I want to write this URL 
https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&output=rss

i wrote like

```
<string-array name="channel_link">
        <item>http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&output=rss</item>
```

...
in string array of string.xml but i am getting an error The reference to entity "cf" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What have you tried? Show us code.

Comment: I think you have to replace & with &amp;.

Comment: <string-array name="channel_link">
        <item>http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&output=rss</item>
</string-array>

Comment: Haresh Chhelana ur right no errors now but when i type this url in address bar it not open xml site of google news it open main page of google news.

Comment: @RahulDevanavar,before you use this url you have convert vice verse using String replace().

Comment: Haresh Chhelan no when its only & it open RSS feed xml feed...but when i replace & with &amp; it not opening same page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply write the string inside CDATA

```
<string-array name="channel_link">
    <item><![CDATA[https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=in&hl=en&output=rss]]></item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1%26cf=all%26ned=in%26hl=en%26output=rss

simply replace `&` with `%26`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
Replace & to &amp; in your String.xml :

<string-array name = "channel_link">
   <item> https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&amp;cf=all&amp;ned=in&amp;hl=en&amp;output=rss</item>
</string-array>

Again replace &amp; to & for actual url:

String[] urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.channel_link);
for(String url : urls){
    url = url.replace("&amp;","&");
}
```